# I want to stop ringtone silence feature while incoming any call and shaking my phone in Intex Cloud Y2

Tags: ringtone, cloud

I have not installed any app in my phone like shake it off or any but whenever I get any call on my Intex Cloud Y2 it gets silenced when I move this phone or shake it.

This case usually occur when I get a call and my phone is in my pocket so it will be automatically silenced while walking on road and I can't notice it.

Does anyone faced this issue? How can I stop this feature in my phone?

I did full factory reset also, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Root your phone and change specific entry in database using sql editor app . I don't have this phone so can't hands on by myself.

Comment: How to do the root and how can I find the same entry in DB?